# How to fix border radius in IE8 (ie7, ie6)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using this CSS:

```
    #main{  
        border-radius: 50px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
            -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
            -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
            -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
            -moz-border-radius: 50px;
            -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 4px;
            -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 4px;
    }
```

It works perfectly in FF, Chrome, IE9(i think) and Safari...
But its soooo ugly in IE8 ,

There are users using IE8, i have tried the .htc [file](http://bit.ly/9Co4sB)  but that dont support border-bottom-right-radius and border-bottom-left-radius...

I'm looking for a JS or HTC file that does support that (or an other solution for this)
I only need it for IE8, but its great if it support IE6 and IE7 aswell!

Thank you!

Comment: You can use the shorthand property for the border-radius which will work with PIE to make the corners different.

Comment: You don't need to use `border-bottom-right-radius` etc. Use the shorthand property: `border-radius:50px 50px 4px 4px` is equivalent to all the ones you posted. You can do that for the vendor-prefixed ones too, so really your entire code should only be three lines. Plus, it's best to put the standard (non-prefixed) declaration *after* the vendor-prefixed ones (because it's standard and should be used by browsers that support it).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could try [CSS Pie](http://css3pie.com/). I've not used it, so I can't vouch for it.

Overall, though: I'd let it go. The absence of rounded corners won't break the experience for users in IE8. More capable browsers get the better experience. Progressive enhancement is a beautiful thing.

Comment: just gonna add this solution. you added first :)

Comment: hmm.. I think it DOES break the experience of users in my design. cause a lot of users comes on my site from there school/office. most of the pc's in school's and office's use IE8. Thats why I want to do this. Thnx for CSS Pie, im gona try that.

Answer (score 0):

**border-bottom-right-radius** Browser Support:

**border-bottom-right-radius** is supported as-is in **Opera 10**.

In order to get it to work in Firefox and Safari, you have to use two related properties:

`-moz-border-radius-bottomright` - for **Firefox 3+**

`-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius -` for **Safari 2+**

It should be supported by **Internet Explorer 9**.

**border-bottom-right-radius** Examples:

*Create a standard rounded corner:*

```
border-bottom-right-radius:1em;
-moz-border-radius-bottomright:1em;
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:1em;
```

*To create a shallower curve:*

```
border-bottom-right-radius:1.6em 1em;
-moz-border-radius-bottomright:1.6em 1em;
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:1.6em 1em;
```

**border-bottom-right-radius Special Notes**:
*Don't forget to set the -moz and -webkit styles as well as the basic border-bottom-right-radius so that your curves show up in most modern browsers.*

Answer (score 0):

**use make a curve border .ping image in photoshop and use it .....because border-radius-bottomleft ,border-radius-bottom right etc not work on ie6-8....only border-radius property work in ....**

*THAT IS NOT POSSIBLE TO SOLVE THAT PROBLEM USING BY CSS SO USE THAT TRICK*

```
background-color: #E8EDEF;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    display: block;
    margin-left: 78px;
    width: 591px;
behavior: url(pie/PIE.htc);
```

> border-radius-bottom right*/ not working in ie6-8