# Border Radius not working in IE7 or 8

Tags: html, css

I am making one class example border-Radius, this class properly work in Firefox and Chrome.

But IE7 and 8 in border radius not working properly.

So How we can fix Border Radius Curves in IE7 or IE8

Comment: border-radius is part of CSS3 [and is only supported by IE9+](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-radius.asp), there are some workarounds you can find easily by searching, refer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9426979/border-radius-for-ie8) or [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9943359/how-to-fix-border-radius-in-ie8-ie7-ie6), for instance.

Comment: You should accept an answer, so the people know your question is solved.

Answer (score 2):

Border radius is a CSS3 feature which IE8 and below do not natively support.

You can take a look at http://css3pie.com/ which is a javascript library which mimics some of the CSS3 features that are available on modern browsers.

Answer (score 0):

we are using pie for css3 property - It will take all browsers , check the link

http://css3pie.com/

Answer (score 0):

border-radius is a css3 property, and IE7 or IE8 doesn't support css3. If you want to put border-radius that badly then please refer this site[Css3pie](http://css3pie.com/) . :)

Answer (score 0):

border-radius in NOT available in [IE8 and lower](http://caniuse.com/#search=border-radius). However, you have basically 3 options:

- in case, it's not crucial not having these rounded borders: just omit it for non-supporting browsers.
- use image-slices (e.g. sliding-door-technique)
- use the proprietary `.htc` and `VML` to emulate rounded corners in IE. One famous and pretty solid framework for this is [CSS3Pie](http://css3pie.com) (but there are several others, just pick the one you like)